# data attribute of HTML 5 is undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In my JSP, in the head part, I have this :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        var labelfooter = jQuery("#myId").data("mylabel");
        var htmlContent = labelfooter +" society ";
        var divContent = jQuery("#myId");
        divContent.text(htmlContent);
    });
</script>
```

Then, in the body part, I have :

```
<div id="myId" data-mylabel="Hello" ></div>
```

As a result, in the browser, I get "undefined society" instead of "Hello society"

Any idea please ?

Comment: Works just fine for me: http://jsfiddle.net/UT3jy/

Comment: Do you have capitalization going on in the actual name?

Comment: @Blender Works for me as well. Maybe use `.single()` if he still has the issue?

Comment: I still have the problem. @epascarello : I didn't understand your question

Comment: @tun_eng What is the actual data attribute you are using? Is it really `data-mylabel`?

Comment: @epascarello : the actual attribute is data-labelFooter, you mean it may be caused by the Capital letter ?

Comment: @epascarello : Yes, this is right, thank you. When removing the capital letter, it works.

Answer (score 5):

The problem here is the fact you have an uppercase in your name. That means something different in the jQuery selctor. Two ways to fix it.

**HTML**

```
<div id="d1" data-fooBar="asdf1"></div>
<div id="d2" data-foo-bar="asdf2"></div>
```

**JavaScript**

```
var x1 = $("#d1").data("foobar"); //selects the camel case one
var x2 = $("#d2").data("fooBar"); //looks for the dash
```

**Example**

[JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/FjVXW/)

Comment: This answer needs more up votes. I've been searching for the past 30min trying to figure this issue out